# Why doesn't this button change text whenever it's clicked, it changes only the first time

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

I have a problem, I am making a function that changes the read status of a book in the array of objects. It should work like this, whenever I press a button and its text content is "Read" it should change to "Not read". And if I press again on the same button, it should go back to "Read", but the problem is, it doesn't, it works only the first time I click on a button.

```
document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("book_status")) {
    let bookCard = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    // console.log(e.target.textContent)
    if (e.target.textContent = 'Not read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Read';
    } else if (e.target.textContent = 'Read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Not read';
    }
  }});
```

Comment: `=` should be `===` or `==`. `=` is for assignment. `===` and  `==` are for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing something you're not setting. Try this to debug:

```
document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("book_status")) {
    let bookCard = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    // console.log(e.target.textContent)
    if (e.target.textContent = 'Not read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Read';
    } else if (e.target.textContent = 'Read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Not read';
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown textContent. e.target.textContent = ' + e.target.textContent);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('e.target.classList DOES NOT include book_status');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator, `==` is for evaluating

```js
document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("book_status")) {
    let bookCard = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    // console.log(e.target.textContent)
    if (e.target.textContent == 'Not read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Read';
    } else if (e.target.textContent == 'Read') {
      e.target.textContent = 'Not read';
    }
  }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the HTML, it is hard to say exactly what could go wrong. But one typo catches my eye immediately:

```
if (e.target.textContent = 'Not read')
```

and

```
} else if (e.target.textContent = 'Read') {
```

should probably have a `==` instead of the `=` ...